# Evaluation of real-valued confluent hypergeometric function with specific complex arguments

Tags: c++, c, special-functions

In my C++ code, I need to evaluate the confluent hypergeometric function ${}_1F_1(a,b;z)$ with complex arguments in a special case. More precisely, I have to compute
$$
e^{-i\phi}{}_1F_1(\ell+1+iZ,2(\ell+1),2i\phi)\, ,
$$
where $Z,\phi$ are real parameters and $\ell\geq 0$ is an integer. I know that this expression is *purely real* (but I cannot for the love of god find the reference for this anymore...).

My problem is that the implementations of ${}_1F_1(a,b;z)$ in `boost` and `gls` only take real arguments.

- Do you have any ideas on how to evaluate the above expression in C++?
- Since we know that the above expression evaluates to real values, is there maybe a trick, that allows using the `boost` or `gls` implementations?

I tried using the integral represenation of ${}_1F_1(a,b;z)$ and perform numerical integration, but this only works for small arguments.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Related: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/kummers-confluent-hypergeometric-for-complex-arguments-in-c-c?rq=1

Comment: If Fortran code is acceptable, have a look at: M. Nardin, W. F. Perger, and A. Bhalla, "Algorithm 707: CONHYP: A numerical evaluator of the confluent hypergeometric function for complex arguments of large magnitudes." *ACM Trans. Math. Software* **18** (3), pp. 345–349.

Comment: I will check out the Fortran code, thank you.

Comment: See a C++ implementation of CONHYP here: https://github.com/spring01/libPSI/blob/5a7806ce3f4aadffa389093e0743a421d21d872d/madness/src/apps/nick/hyp.cc

Comment: I will give that one a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I found a solution myself, and in case someone else stumbles upon this question, I want to share it.

Shortly after posting this question, I found out that the type of expression I want to evaluate goes under the name of [Coulomb wave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_wave_function). As so often, finding the proper terminology for the problem can be half the solution.

Coulomb wavefunctions are implemented in [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), but the arguments are limited to certain domains. The C library [arb](https://arblib.org/) also has an implementation and is applicable over a wider range of arguments. But it is also slower. So I ended up with the following combination of GSL and arb.

```cpp
#include "arb_hypgeom.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_coulomb.h>

double Coulomb_Wave_ARB(int L, double eta, double rho)
{
    double result;
    slong prec;
    arb_t F, l, eta_2, rho_2;
    arb_init(F);
    arb_init(l);
    arb_init(eta_2);
    arb_init(rho_2);
    arb_set_d(l, L);
    arb_set_d(eta_2, eta);
    arb_set_d(rho_2, rho);
    for(prec = 80;; prec *= 2)
    {
        arb_hypgeom_coulomb(F, NULL, l, eta_2, rho_2, prec);
        if(arb_rel_accuracy_bits(F) >= 53)
        {
            result = arf_get_d(arb_midref(F), ARF_RND_NEAR);
            break;
        }
        else if(prec > 10000)
        {
            result = NAN;
            break;
        }
    }
    arb_clear(F);
    arb_clear(eta_2);
    arb_clear(rho_2);
    arb_clear(l);
    return result;
}

double Coulomb_Wave_GSL(int L, double eta, double rho, int& status)
{
    double fc_array[1];
    double F_exponent[1];
    status = gsl_sf_coulomb_wave_F_array(L, 0, eta, rho, fc_array, F_exponent);
    return fc_array[0];
}

double Coulomb_Wave(int L, double eta, double rho)
{
    int status;
    double cw = Coulomb_Wave_GSL(L, eta, rho, status);
    if(status != 0 || std::isnan(cw))
        cw = Coulomb_Wave_ARB(L, eta, rho);
    return cw;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your replies and inputs!

Comment: Thank you for providing this! How much slower is ``arb`` compared to ``gsl`` ?

Comment: I do not remember running speed tests. But it shouldn't be hard to check the performance  with the given code.

Comment: I have manged to call the CONHYP fortran code/subroutines from a CPP program, by linking together 2 .o files. I can now get values of 1F1 at any imaginary argument. I have compared a fair range of input arguments and the original CONHYP from fortran beats ``arb`` in terms of speed at any argument.

Comment: Interesting! If the difference in performance is significant, please feel free to share the way you did that in its own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you go by the power series route, Kummer's function can be expressed as:

$
M(a, b, z) = \Gamma(b) \sum_{s = 0}^\infty \cfrac{(a)_s}{\Gamma(b+s) s!} \, z^s
$

(see https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2)

The complex variable appears only in $z^s$ which can be evaluated with std::pow(std::complex) : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow.

There are numerous papers on less naive ways of evaluating these functions.  But the basic approach should give you a good start.

Comment: Well, you did not touch the main problem here which is $a$ is complex here. Is there any guarantee that your series would work when $a$ is complex?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer      The summation can be split into a real part and an imaginary part (in $a$) and is not too problematic.

Comment: How would you split the real and imaginary parts of the $(a)_{s}$? Note that $Z$ is not even an integer number. If possible, please write it explicitly for real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer: Sorry, I probably don't understand your question.  A recurrence relation should be easy to use to calculate $(a)_s$ which is a product of terms of the form $a(a+1)$ where $a = a_1 + i a_2$.

Comment: I know there is a recurrence relation to calculate $(a)_{s}$ but my point is that there is no reason to believe that the series that you provided here would converge to give the correct answer. In fact, the series that you provided is convergent for real $a$ it doesn’t necessarily shows that it would be convergent for complex $a$ values as well. Do you have any evidence that this would work for complex $a$ values? My guess is that it won’t work based on OP’s claim that numerical integration only work for small values.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer:  That's a different issue.   Like I said, it's a naive approach that should be checked. If we are going to be pedantic, we're not even sure that the governing ODE has a solution if $a$ is complex and whether the function can be called a hypergeometric confluent function.  Perhaps that's the question the OP should address.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. The above expression appears in a specific solution of the Schrödinger equation (continuum solution of hydrogen basically). It's not a problem to evaluate the function in Mathematica or python.

Comment: @user157765: Which Python library are you using?  The standard ones in scipy all assume real $a$.

Comment: I used [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/) in python.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee It seems indeed mpmath is able to evaluate the $_{1}F_{1}$ for complex $a$ and $b$ values: https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html#hyp1f1